# Android app not getting installed in the emulator after it shows installation success on the console

Tags: android

I tried it on a phone and an emulator, but even though the build is success, the app is not getting installed in the emulator. Every-time, I 've to run the app from the IDE to get it to work. Previously,once I ran the app, it used to get installed on the emulator.

This is my AndroidManifest.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.main"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <!-- Set minimum AndroidSDk version -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

    <!-- user permissions  -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>


    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.App" android:allowClearUserData="true" android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">

        <!-- SplashScreen :  make this Activity as App launcher -->
                <activity android:name="com.App.main.SplashScreen" android:label="@string/app_name"
                    >
                   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        <!-- end of SplashScreen -->

        <!-- MainActivity -->
                <activity android:name="com.apps.main.AppMainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:noHistory="true" ></activity>
                <!-- end of MainActivity -->


<!-- Account activities -->

        <!-- User Login : set no history available once user logged-in      -->
        <activity 
            android:name="com.apps.main.account.Login" 
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>

        <!-- User Registeration  -->
        <activity 
            android:name="com.apps.main.account.Register"
            android:noHistory="true">
        </activity>


<!-- end of Acount activities  -->



                </application>
</manifest>
```

No, nothing on the log cat. As I said, the app builds successfully.

Comment: logcat please while trying to install.

Comment: building is not equal to installing. The building may succeed. How are installing the app? See mah's answer and check your version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove

> android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

from your application tag .

Thats it ;)

Comment: Could you explain why that should help? (not that it is wrong, just an explanation should be added :) )

Answer (score 0):

Show the logcat output at the time of the install failure; that is likely to give you the exact reason it won't install.

I see from your manifest that it's version 1, and you state that you've installed it previously though your IDE. When you try to install by hand, are you using install's `-r` option? `adb install -r my.apk` -- the -r is needed to force replacing the APK even though its version is not greater than that of the already-installed version. Alternatively, build with a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that ended up working for me was found in this thread: [Android: Installed App icon is not visible in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150702/android-installed-app-icon-is-not-visible-in-emulator)

The application was installing successfully but the intent was not set in the manifests activity tag. Hope this helps anyone who is still searching for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with the **android:installLocation="preferExternal"** and **androidSDK 7**.

Please verify that android version 2.1 supports installLocation="preferExternal"